# Array value overwrites instead of retaining old value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is what I want.

User enters a numerical input. If he enters 2, the code prompts to enter two player names.

The player names are stored in an array. There is a 'next' button in the page, when user clicks it, the code prompts to enter another two names.

The next is the tricky part: Right now there are four names entered on two separate sessions. Now I need a nested array should hold the usernames in separate arrays based on the session.

I've tried many codes but only the following at least comes closer. 
But what happens is, every time user enters a new list of usernames, a new array is created but previous arrays are also over written.

```js
var TotalNumOfPlayers = prompt("Enter The Total Number Of Players! (For example 2)");
var nameOfPlayers = [];
var loopThroughAllNames = new Array(new Array());
var NextList = document.querySelector("#NextList");
var tempArr = [];

addValue();

function addValue() {
  for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumOfPlayers; i++) {
    tempArr[i] = prompt("Enter Player name "+(i+1));
  }

  loopThroughAllNames.push(tempArr);
}

NextList.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addValue();

});
```

```html
<button id="NextList">Next list</button>
```

Comment: because you always start at zero...

Comment: Sorry. This doesn't work. I just tried it out. It still overwrites the values. Thank you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for-loop always starts from 0 for the same tempArr (initialized once outside the `addValue` method), hence it overwrites the previous entries.

```
for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumOfPlayers; i++) {
    tempArr[i] = prompt("Enter Player name "+(i+1));
  }
```

You need to initialize the `tempArr` array inside the `addValue` method.

**Demo**

```js
var loopThroughAllNames = [];
var TotalNumOfPlayers = prompt("Enter The Total Number Of Players!");
addValue();

function addValue () 
{
  var tempArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumOfPlayers; i++) {
    tempArr[i] = prompt("Enter Player name");
  }
  loopThroughAllNames.push(tempArr);  
  console.log( loopThroughAllNames );
}

var NextList = document.querySelector("#NextList");
NextList.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addValue( );
});
```

```html
<button id="NextList">Next list</button>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Nope, just tested. If tempArr is not initialized everytime, then it overwrites the previous values.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, I fixed it. I thought this is what OP wanted.

Comment: It actually still does not work. It does not ask for names unless I click next list - you need the initial addValue()

Comment: Seems like you were the first one to respond with exactly what I wanted. Thank you. It works perfect.

Comment: @mplungjan: That's fine. I was expecting that only. Only when the button is clicked, code will prompt user to enter names. Or else it would be infinite loop isn't it?

Comment: Now this one does it too

Answer (score 3):

Check below link

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chcnzyhy/3/)

```js
var TotalNumOfPlayers = prompt("Enter The Total Number Of Players! (For example 2)");
var loopThroughAllNames = [];
var NextList = document.querySelector("#NextList");

addValue();

function addValue() {
  var tempArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumOfPlayers; i++) {
    tempArr[i] = prompt("Enter Player name " + (i + 1));
  }

  loopThroughAllNames.push(tempArr);
}

NextList.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addValue();
  document.write(JSON.stringify(loopThroughAllNames));
});
```

```html
<button id="NextList">Next list</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am creating an array of arrays to insert names. `tempArr` is declared as empty inside `addValue` and later pushed into global array `allnames`

```js
var TotalNumOfPlayers = prompt("Enter The Total Number Of Players! (For example 2)");
var nameOfPlayers = [];
var loopThroughAllNames = new Array(new Array());
var NextList = document.querySelector("#NextList");
var allnames = [];

addValue();

function addValue() {
  var tempArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumOfPlayers; i++) {
    tempArr[i] = prompt("Enter Player name "+(i+1));
  }

  loopThroughAllNames.push(tempArr);
  allnames.push(tempArr);
}

NextList.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addValue();
  console.log(allnames)
});
```

```html
<button id="NextList">Next list</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Rajkumar. It works beautifully. Was scratching my head. The code works because the tempArr stays only inside the function "addValue". Thank you once again.