# Javascript Array overwriting previous data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am coding some stuff for Adobe Illustrator and am running into an issue with this code below. If I have an object set to 80 opacity for mesh<110 it will change the object to 54 opacity per the array. Then the array gets to 54 and changes what was just changed for 80 to 45 and 45 to 39 and so on.

When all is said and done every object from 99-28 is set to 28 and every object from 27-1 is set to 27.

I have tried rearranging the array so that it goes from 27-0 then 28-100 hoping that it would avoid the split but still has the same issue.

Think I may have found the answer but not sure how to interpret it for this code:[STACK LINK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633389/array-value-overwrites-instead-of-retaining-old-value-javascript/47633493#47633493)

```js
function test() {
    var docRef = app.activeDocument;
    var layers = docRef.layers;
    var paths = docRef.pathItems;
    var items = docRef.selection;
    var meshtitle = "Mesh?"
    var mesh = Number(prompt("meshcount", 180, meshtitle));
    if (mesh <= 110) {
        var opacityRelationships = {
            "100": 100, "99": 99, "98": 98, "97": 97, "96": 68, "95": 67, "94": 66, "93": 65, "92": 64, "91": 63, "90": 63, "89": 62, "88": 61, "87": 61, "86": 60, "85": 59, "84": 58, "83": 57, "82": 56, "81": 55, "80": 54, "79": 53, "78": 53, "77": 52, "76": 52, "75": 52, "74": 51, "73": 51, "72": 51, "71": 50, "70": 50, "69": 50, "68": 49, "67": 49, "66": 49, "65": 48, "64": 48, "63": 48, "62": 47, "61": 47, "60": 47, "59": 46, "58": 46, "57": 46, "56": 46, "55": 45, "54": 45, "53": 45, "52": 44, "51": 44, "50": 44, "49": 43, "48": 42, "47": 41, "46": 40, "45": 39, "44": 39, "43": 38, "42": 37, "41": 37, "40": 36, "39": 35, "38": 34, "37": 34, "36": 33, "35": 33, "34": 32, "33": 32, "32": 31, "31": 30, "30": 29, "29": 28, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 27, "25": 26, "24": 26, "23": 25, "22": 25, "21": 24, "20": 24, "19": 24, "18": 23, "17": 23, "16": 22, "15": 22, "14": 21, "13": 21, "12": 20, "11": 20, "10": 20, "9": 19, "8": 18, "7": 17, "6": 16, "5": 15, "4": 14, "3": 13, "2": 12, "1": 11, "0": 0
        }
    }
    if (mesh > 110 && mesh <= 180) {
        var opacityRelationships = {
            "100": 40, "99": 40, "98": 40, "97": 40, "96": 40, "95": 40, "94": 40, "93": 10, "92": 10, "91": 10, "90": 10, "89": 10, "88": 10, "87": 10, "86": 86, "85": 85, "84": 84, "83": 83, "82": 82, "81": 81, "80": 80, "79": 79, "78": 78, "77": 77, "76": 76, "75": 75, "74": 74, "73": 73, "72": 72, "71": 71, "70": 70, "69": 69, "68": 68, "67": 67, "66": 66, "65": 65, "64": 64, "63": 63, "62": 62, "61": 61, "60": 10, "59": 59, "58": 58, "57": 57, "56": 56, "55": 55, "54": 54, "53": 53, "52": 52, "51": 51, "50": 50, "49": 49, "48": 48, "47": 47, "46": 46, "45": 45, "44": 44, "43": 43, "42": 42, "41": 41, "40": 40, "39": 39, "38": 38, "37": 37, "36": 36, "35": 35, "34": 34, "33": 33, "32": 32, "31": 31, "30": 30, "29": 29, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 26, "25": 25, "24": 24, "23": 23, "22": 22, "21": 21, "20": 20, "19": 19, "18": 18, "17": 17, "16": 16, "15": 15, "14": 14, "13": 13, "12": 12, "11": 11, "10": 10, "9": 9, "8": 8, "7": 7, "6": 6, "5": 5, "4": 4, "3": 3, "2": 2, "1": 1, "0": 0
        }
    }
    if (mesh > 180 && mesh <= 255) {
        var opacityRelationships = {
            "100": 55, "99": 55, "98": 55, "97": 55, "96": 55, "95": 55, "94": 55, "93": 55, "92": 10, "91": 10, "90": 10, "89": 10, "88": 10, "87": 10, "86": 86, "85": 85, "84": 84, "83": 83, "82": 82, "81": 81, "80": 80, "79": 79, "78": 78, "77": 77, "76": 76, "75": 75, "74": 74, "73": 73, "72": 72, "71": 71, "70": 70, "69": 69, "68": 68, "67": 67, "66": 66, "65": 65, "64": 64, "63": 63, "62": 62, "61": 61, "60": 10, "59": 59, "58": 58, "57": 57, "56": 56, "55": 55, "54": 54, "53": 53, "52": 52, "51": 51, "50": 50, "49": 49, "48": 48, "47": 47, "46": 46, "45": 45, "44": 44, "43": 43, "42": 42, "41": 41, "40": 40, "39": 39, "38": 38, "37": 37, "36": 36, "35": 35, "34": 34, "33": 33, "32": 32, "31": 31, "30": 30, "29": 29, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 26, "25": 25, "24": 24, "23": 23, "22": 22, "21": 21, "20": 20, "19": 19, "18": 18, "17": 17, "16": 16, "15": 15, "14": 14, "13": 13, "12": 12, "11": 11, "10": 10, "9": 9, "8": 8, "7": 7, "6": 6, "5": 5, "4": 4, "3": 3, "2": 2, "1": 1, "0": 0
        }
    }
    if (mesh > 255) {
        var opacityRelationships = {
            "100": 80, "99": 80, "98": 80, "97": 80, "96": 80, "95": 80, "94": 80, "93": 80, "92": 10, "91": 10, "90": 10, "89": 10, "88": 10, "87": 10, "86": 86, "85": 85, "84": 84, "83": 83, "82": 82, "81": 81, "80": 80, "79": 79, "78": 78, "77": 77, "76": 76, "75": 75, "74": 74, "73": 73, "72": 72, "71": 71, "70": 70, "69": 69, "68": 68, "67": 67, "66": 66, "65": 65, "64": 64, "63": 63, "62": 62, "61": 61, "60": 10, "59": 59, "58": 58, "57": 57, "56": 56, "55": 55, "54": 54, "53": 53, "52": 52, "51": 51, "50": 50, "49": 49, "48": 48, "47": 47, "46": 46, "45": 45, "44": 44, "43": 43, "42": 42, "41": 41, "40": 40, "39": 39, "38": 38, "37": 37, "36": 36, "35": 35, "34": 34, "33": 33, "32": 32, "31": 31, "30": 30, "29": 29, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 26, "25": 25, "24": 24, "23": 23, "22": 22, "21": 21, "20": 20, "19": 19, "18": 18, "17": 17, "16": 16, "15": 15, "14": 14, "13": 13, "12": 12, "11": 11, "10": 10, "9": 9, "8": 8, "7": 7, "6": 6, "5": 5, "4": 4, "3": 3, "2": 2, "1": 1, "0": 0
        }
    }

    function updateOpacity(item) {
        var curOpacity = Math.floor(item.opacity).toString();
        item.opacity = opacityRelationships[curOpacity];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        if (paths[i].fillColor == '[GradientColor]') {
            for (var x = 0, len = paths.length; x < len; x++) {
                for (var y = 0; y < paths[i].fillColor.gradient.gradientStops.length; y++) {
                    updateOpacity(paths[i].fillColor.gradient.gradientStops[y]);
                }
            }
        } else if (paths[i].fillColor == '[SpotColor]') {
            for (var x = 0, len = layers.length; x < len; x++) {
                for (var y = 0, yLen = layers[x].pageItems.length; y < yLen; y++) {
                    updateOpacity(layers[x].pageItems[y]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
test();
```

Comment: is it possible to make the array to execute (for example) x value 28-0 descending first then x value 29-100 ascending? This would prevent overwriting previous entry changes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Functions were looping on top of eachother and I needed them to run once, collectively (i think i said that right).

```js
function test() {
        var docRef = app.activeDocument;
        var layers = docRef.layers;
        var paths = docRef.pathItems;
        var items = docRef.selection;
        var meshtitle = "Mesh?"
        var mesh = Number(prompt("meshcount", 180, meshtitle));
        if (mesh <= 110) {
            var opacityRelationships = {
                "100": 100, "99": 99, "98": 98, "97": 97, "96": 68, "95": 67, "94": 66, "93": 65, "92": 64, "91": 63, "90": 63, "89": 62, "88": 61, "87": 61, "86": 60, "85": 59, "84": 58, "83": 57, "82": 56, "81": 55, "80": 54, "79": 53, "78": 53, "77": 52, "76": 52, "75": 52, "74": 51, "73": 51, "72": 51, "71": 50, "70": 50, "69": 50, "68": 49, "67": 49, "66": 49, "65": 48, "64": 48, "63": 48, "62": 47, "61": 47, "60": 47, "59": 46, "58": 46, "57": 46, "56": 46, "55": 45, "54": 45, "53": 45, "52": 44, "51": 44, "50": 44, "49": 43, "48": 42, "47": 41, "46": 40, "45": 39, "44": 39, "43": 38, "42": 37, "41": 37, "40": 36, "39": 35, "38": 34, "37": 34, "36": 33, "35": 33, "34": 32, "33": 32, "32": 31, "31": 30, "30": 29, "29": 28, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 27, "25": 26, "24": 26, "23": 25, "22": 25, "21": 24, "20": 24, "19": 24, "18": 23, "17": 23, "16": 22, "15": 22, "14": 21, "13": 21, "12": 20, "11": 20, "10": 20, "9": 19, "8": 18, "7": 17, "6": 16, "5": 15, "4": 14, "3": 13, "2": 12, "1": 11, "0": 0
            }
        }
        if (mesh > 110 && mesh <= 180) {
            var opacityRelationships = {
                "100": 40, "99": 40, "98": 40, "97": 40, "96": 40, "95": 40, "94": 40, "93": 10, "92": 10, "91": 10, "90": 10, "89": 10, "88": 10, "87": 10, "86": 86, "85": 85, "84": 84, "83": 83, "82": 82, "81": 81, "80": 80, "79": 79, "78": 78, "77": 77, "76": 76, "75": 75, "74": 74, "73": 73, "72": 72, "71": 71, "70": 70, "69": 69, "68": 68, "67": 67, "66": 66, "65": 65, "64": 64, "63": 63, "62": 62, "61": 61, "60": 10, "59": 59, "58": 58, "57": 57, "56": 56, "55": 55, "54": 54, "53": 53, "52": 52, "51": 51, "50": 50, "49": 49, "48": 48, "47": 47, "46": 46, "45": 45, "44": 44, "43": 43, "42": 42, "41": 41, "40": 40, "39": 39, "38": 38, "37": 37, "36": 36, "35": 35, "34": 34, "33": 33, "32": 32, "31": 31, "30": 30, "29": 29, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 26, "25": 25, "24": 24, "23": 23, "22": 22, "21": 21, "20": 20, "19": 19, "18": 18, "17": 17, "16": 16, "15": 15, "14": 14, "13": 13, "12": 12, "11": 11, "10": 10, "9": 9, "8": 8, "7": 7, "6": 6, "5": 5, "4": 4, "3": 3, "2": 2, "1": 1, "0": 0
            }
        }
        if (mesh > 180 && mesh <= 255) {
            var opacityRelationships = {
                "100": 55, "99": 55, "98": 55, "97": 55, "96": 55, "95": 55, "94": 55, "93": 55, "92": 10, "91": 10, "90": 10, "89": 10, "88": 10, "87": 10, "86": 86, "85": 85, "84": 84, "83": 83, "82": 82, "81": 81, "80": 80, "79": 79, "78": 78, "77": 77, "76": 76, "75": 75, "74": 74, "73": 73, "72": 72, "71": 71, "70": 70, "69": 69, "68": 68, "67": 67, "66": 66, "65": 65, "64": 64, "63": 63, "62": 62, "61": 61, "60": 10, "59": 59, "58": 58, "57": 57, "56": 56, "55": 55, "54": 54, "53": 53, "52": 52, "51": 51, "50": 50, "49": 49, "48": 48, "47": 47, "46": 46, "45": 45, "44": 44, "43": 43, "42": 42, "41": 41, "40": 40, "39": 39, "38": 38, "37": 37, "36": 36, "35": 35, "34": 34, "33": 33, "32": 32, "31": 31, "30": 30, "29": 29, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 26, "25": 25, "24": 24, "23": 23, "22": 22, "21": 21, "20": 20, "19": 19, "18": 18, "17": 17, "16": 16, "15": 15, "14": 14, "13": 13, "12": 12, "11": 11, "10": 10, "9": 9, "8": 8, "7": 7, "6": 6, "5": 5, "4": 4, "3": 3, "2": 2, "1": 1, "0": 0
            }
        }
        if (mesh > 255) {
            var opacityRelationships = {
                "100": 80, "99": 80, "98": 80, "97": 80, "96": 80, "95": 80, "94": 80, "93": 80, "92": 10, "91": 10, "90": 10, "89": 10, "88": 10, "87": 10, "86": 86, "85": 85, "84": 84, "83": 83, "82": 82, "81": 81, "80": 80, "79": 79, "78": 78, "77": 77, "76": 76, "75": 75, "74": 74, "73": 73, "72": 72, "71": 71, "70": 70, "69": 69, "68": 68, "67": 67, "66": 66, "65": 65, "64": 64, "63": 63, "62": 62, "61": 61, "60": 10, "59": 59, "58": 58, "57": 57, "56": 56, "55": 55, "54": 54, "53": 53, "52": 52, "51": 51, "50": 50, "49": 49, "48": 48, "47": 47, "46": 46, "45": 45, "44": 44, "43": 43, "42": 42, "41": 41, "40": 40, "39": 39, "38": 38, "37": 37, "36": 36, "35": 35, "34": 34, "33": 33, "32": 32, "31": 31, "30": 30, "29": 29, "28": 28, "27": 27, "26": 26, "25": 25, "24": 24, "23": 23, "22": 22, "21": 21, "20": 20, "19": 19, "18": 18, "17": 17, "16": 16, "15": 15, "14": 14, "13": 13, "12": 12, "11": 11, "10": 10, "9": 9, "8": 8, "7": 7, "6": 6, "5": 5, "4": 4, "3": 3, "2": 2, "1": 1, "0": 0
            }
        }

      for (var i=0,len = paths.length;i<len;i++) {
        if (paths[i].fillColor == '[GradientColor]') {
   for (var z = 0; z < paths[i].fillColor.gradient.gradientStops.length; z++) {
            function updateOpacityGradient(item){
                var curOpacity = Math.floor(item.opacity);
         item.opacity = opacityRelationships[curOpacity];
     }
  updateOpacityGradient(paths[i].fillColor.gradient.gradientStops[z]);
   }
 }
 
   }
   
    for (var j=0,len = paths.length;j<len;j++) {
    for (var r=0,len = layers.length;r<len;r++){
 if (paths[j].fillColor == '[SpotColor]') {
    for (var y=0,yLen = layers[r].pageItems.length;y<yLen;y++) {
     function updateOpacitySpot(item2){
                var curOpacity = Math.floor(item2.opacity).toString();
         item2.opacity = opacityRelationships[curOpacity]; 
     }
  updateOpacitySpot(layers[r].pageItems[y]);
    }
        }
   }
   }
    }test();
```